# Сохранение баллов за каждый верный\неверный ответ

Tags: javascript

Я написала программу которая составляет рандомные примеры, однако теперь у меня возник вопрос: как каждый раз за каждый ответ сохранять значение переменной `result_answer` и прибавлять к ней новый? Помогите пожалуйста!

```
function kinder_training() {
    var i = 0; // Количество вопросов
    for (i; i < 13; i++) {
        var max = 5; // Максимальное количество чисел
        var min = 2; // Минимальное количество чисел
        var len;  // Количество чисел
        var a = 1;  // Левая граница интервала
        var b = 10; // Правая граница интервала
        var sum = 0;  // Сумматор
        var counter = 0;  // Счетчик чисел
        var number;       // Случайное число
        var str = "";     // Строка для вывода.
        var points = 0; //Все баллы
        var result_answer; //Балл за ответ
        len = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;//Длина количества чисел 
            while (counter < len)//Создаем рандомный пример
                {
                    number = Math.floor(a + (b-a+1)*Math.random());
                    if (number%2) continue;
                    sum += number;
                    str += number;
                    if (counter < len-1) str += " + ";
                    else str += " = ";
                    counter++;
                }

        var conclusion = prompt(str, 'Enter result here');  
        var result = sum; 
        if (conclusion != result) { //Если введенный ответ не соответствует верному то -
            alert('Your answer is wrong!');
            result_answer = 0; //Начисляется ноль баллов
        }

        else { //В другом случае -
            alert('Your answer is right!');
            result_answer = 1; //Начисляется один балл
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить строку `result_answer = 1; // Начисляется один балл` на `result_answer += 1; // Начисляется один балл`

Comment: @stackanon, тогда уж и при неправильном ответе надо + добавлять, чтобы полностью все не сбрасывалось

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно, чтобы result_answer показывал кол-во баллов, которые набирает пользователь, то ожидается, что будет какой-то внешний "счетчик", который эти баллы "соберет". Что я имею ввиду

```
function kinder_training() {

    var i = 0;
    var result_answer = 0; // вынес счетчик вне цикла
    ...
    if (conclusion != result) {
        ...
        result_answer += 0; // можно вообще удалить
        // или же намеренно указать = 0, чтобы обнулить результат при неверном ответе
    }else{
        result_answer +=1;
    }
```